# How can I get selected item in DropDownList ASP control in Page_Load method?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have DropDownList inside my ASP page.

When selection changed postback accured and the Page_Load method fired.

I need to get selected item(selectedValue and selectedIndex) in Page_Load method.

I know that I can use selectedIndexChanged event handler, but in my case it is not

suitable solution because of incorrect architecture.

Any idea how to get selected item in DropDownList control in Page_Load method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be OK as long as you check for postback -

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsPostBack)
   {
       var index = ddlDropDown.SelectedIndex;
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

I'm assuming that the control isn't dynamically created.

Answer (score 2):

With incorrect architecture is it useful to write

```
var selectedValue = Request.Params[drpDownList.UniqueID];
```